# How to prevent re-render when using sockets on React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this problem with my code, it likes to re-render and reconnect to the server multiple times, and I'd like to have it so it'll connect when they log in, meaning that it would have to use my "useAuth()" function which uses a different context.

Is there any way to prevent the re-render so it doesn't reconnect multiple times and only connects once?

This is my code:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useAuth } from "./AuthContext";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const SocketContext = React.createContext({});

export const SocketProvider = ({ children }) => {
   const { isAuthenticated, user } = useAuth();
   useEffect(() => {
      if (isAuthenticated) {
         const socket = io("ws://localhost:3002", {
            reconnectionDelayMax: 10000,
            auth: {
               token: user.socketAuth,
            },
         });

         socket.on("connect_error", (err) => {
            if (err instanceof Error) {
               console.log(err.message);
               console.log(err.data);
            }
         });
      }
   }, []);
   return <SocketContext.Provider value="">{children}</SocketContext.Provider>;
};
```

Comment: You are just invoking the useEffect on initial render so unless you are remounting the SocketProvider somehow from parent the behaviour you are describing shouldn't happen. You can log inside your useEffect to check if it is being called multiple times to know whether your component is remounting

Comment: pass an empty dependency array in your useEffect Hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I fixed the issue, it was working how it was supposed to be. It was the server that wasn't accepting the connection and it just kept logging the ID of the socket and not actually letting it connect.

```js
io.use(async (socket, next) => {
   const user = await User.findOne({ socketAuth: socket.handshake.auth.token });
   if (!user) {
      const err = new Error("Unauthorized");
      err.data = { message: "Unauthorized, please try again later." };
      next(err);
   }
   next(); // New line added to allow connection
});
```